# STOMP subscription performance. It is better to have only one subscription?

Tags: javascript, websocket, stomp

I am developing an application with STOMP Over WebSocket. In order to develope an scalable and good performance application. What of the next STOMP subscription solutions is better in terms of the the resources usage?

**Solution A** (STOMP standard: to have multiple subscription) example:

```
 stompClient.subscribe("/event1", function (message) {
 });
 stompClient.subscribe("/event2", function (message) {
 });
 .....
```

**Solution B** (to have only one subscription with multiple functions) example:

```
 stompClient.subscribe("/events", function (message) {
 switch (message.event) {
    case "event1": myFunction1(message)
        break;
    case "event2":myFunction2(message)
        break;
 .....
 });
```

Which solution is better when there are hundred of subscriptions at the same session? can the server and the browser handle multiple subscriptions with hardly any difference in performance?

I am using this javascript STOMP javascript library http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/ and The SPRING BOOT websocket configuration. The comunication arquitecture is web browser as sending and consumming and spring server as broker.

Comment: Hmm, my gut reaction would be that multiple subscriptions should be better. Not performance-wise but reading and maintaining-wise. I doubt there would be a significant performance difference. Having one subscription means that you now have to engineer your own dispatch which the client would already be doing for you, so you'd be reimplementing some piece of functionality.

Comment: Ultimately the performance is going to be based on the broker implementation you're using. However, you don't specify what broker you're using so it's hard to provide any conclusive answers.

Comment: @JustinBertram What do you mean with broker? Server solution or javascript library?

Comment: @Martin, I'm talking about the server to which you're sending the messages and from which you're consuming them. See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) or perhaps [the STOMP specification overview](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) for further details.

Comment: I have been updated the question with your suggestions.